# return list of images as bytes in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, razor

I am trying to return a list of images as bytes to display on my view.
I know how to return a single image by putting this in my controller

```
public FileContentResult DisplayImages(string packageID)

{

            byte[] byteArray = imageConverter.GetImageAsBytes(
                "\\filepath-to-image.jpeg");

            return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "image/jpeg"
}
```

How do I modify this to return a list of byte[] and then according call it in my View.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you'll call this action from javascript.
In this case you could use the Json actionresult type to do this.

```
public ActionResult DisplayImages(string packageID)
{
  byte[] byteArray = imageConverter.GetImageAsBytes(@"\filepath-to-image.jpeg");
  return Json(new { imageList = new List<Byte[]>() { byteArray } });
}
```

you'll get an object with a imageList property which will be an Array of Array of Byte.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes I am calling the controller function via javascript. Will I have to specify the content-type in my view when calling?

Comment: I am currently just using <img src = @Html.ActionLink("Controller/Action") /> to render the image. Not sure how I would do this with a list of array bytes returned as json

Comment: You won't be able to do a list of images in a single request unless you do some sort of CSS sprite (combine it to a single image), make multiple requests, or do some binary manipulation with an HTML 5 canvas or something, so may want to explore a different route.  The multiple request is probably the easiest.

Comment: Multiple requests is not really an option since I'm querying the database based on the packageID which returns 0 or many images

Comment: In that case it's a lot more difficult to get the thing done. As far as I know, you can't do this with just one request. You could break it up in 2 different requests, 1 to fetch the binaries from the database into the user session / webserver cache and returns an identifier and the number of images fetched and another which will take the identifier and a number as parameter and outputs the corresponding image data.